# Trigger Cant see files not shared with running user

Tags: trigger, contentversion

I have a trigger that counts attachments and files on an opportunity and rolls this up to the opp. However the trigger only sees files that are shared with the user that is executing it

Is there a way around this all i can see is for classes without sharing

```
trigger CountAttahcments on Opportunity (before Update) {

    list<ContentVersion> ContentsVersion = [Select id From ContentVersion Where associatedopplinkID__c in :trigger.new];
    List<Attachment> Attch = [Select id from Attachment Where Parentid in : Trigger.new];
    List<Opportunity> OppsUpdate = new list<Opportunity>();

    integer Attachmentcount = ContentsVersion.size() + Attch.size();

    For(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
        opp.attachments__C = Attachmentcount;

    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: is `without sharing` not an option?

Comment: if any answers have solved this issue for you, please mark them as accepted so that others can benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, by design, when running with sharing, objects not visible to the running user are not visible. And, assuming you want to keep using `with sharing` for some other reason (common classes); you could switch to a different running user using this handy trick

- Create a Platform Event called `Opportunity_Attachment_Counter__e` with a field called `Opportunity_Id__c`
- Use code in your trigger something like this

  ```
   Opportunity_Attachment_Counter__e[] platevents = new List<Opportunity_Attachment_Counter__e>();
   for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
     platEvents.add(new Opportunity_Attachment_Counter__e(
   Opportunity_Id__c = o.Id));
   }
   EventBus.publish(platEvents);
  ```

Then , code a trigger on afterInsert for `Opportunity_Attachment_Counter__e` that does the counting and database updating

> Platform Event triggers always run with context user = `Automated
>   Process` that can see all Sobjects

Answer (score 0):

[here is a nice blog to help explain the different modes in a trigger context.](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/system-mode-or-god-mode-in-apex-gotchas/)
As to your actual question. You should probably handle the process you need in a without sharing context in a handler.

```
public without sharing class OpportunityAttachmentRollup {

    public static void handleRollup( List<SObject> records ){
        ....
    }

}
```

Reference this in your trigger using `OpportunityAttachmentRollup.handleRollup( Trigger.new );`